How should I include docs directory in pyproject.toml?
I have a simple pyproject file using setuptools for a package with a src layout (using auto discovery).
Recently I added a docs directory. I thought the auto discovery would pick it up and add it to the source package, but this did not happen. Is this normal?
If it is normal then what should I do to include the docs directory in the source package?
I built the package with the existing pyproject.toml and it produced a source package which did not include the docs directory.
Directory layout:
.
├── AUTHORS
├── docs
│   ├── example1.md
│   └── example2.md
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── vtjson
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── vtjson.py
└── tests
    └── test_vtjson.py

Pyproject file:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "vtjson"
dynamic = ["version"]
authors = [
  { name="Michel Van den Bergh", email="vdbergh@example.org" },
]
description = "A lightweight package for validating JSON like Python objects"
readme = "README.md"
dependencies = ["dnspython", "email_validator", "idna", "python-magic", "typing_extensions"]
requires-python = ">=3.7"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[tool.setuptools]
#py-modules = ["vtjson"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "vtjson.vtjson.__version__"}

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/vdbergh/vtjson"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/vdbergh/vtjson/issues"


Your docs directory is outside of the package root directory it will be installed directly into site-packages not under any package — is it ok for you and your users? IMO it's not.

I don't think the question is about installing the docs, but simply about having the docs in the source distribution (which means the docs should not be in the wheel). -- I think the solution is to add the docs directory in the MANIFEST.in file. -- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html -- https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html
